# Result data after grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the data as below

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02AD04-0037 | 20 | 1 |
| 02AI01-0001 | 50 | 1 |
| 02AI01-0001 | 15 | 2 |
| 02AI01-0001 | 50 | 3 |
| 02AI01-0002 | 50 | 1 |
| 02AI01-0002 | 15 | 2 |
| 02AI01-0002 | 50 | 3 |
| 02AI01-0006 | 25 | 1 |
| 02AI01-0006 | 15 | 2 |
| 02AI01-0006 | 25 | 3 |
| 02AI01-0006 | 50 | 4 |
| 02AI01-0006 | 25 | 5 |

I want to group the data as below

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 02AD04-0037 | 20 |
| 02AI01-0001 | 50/15 |
| 02AI01-0002 | 50/15 |
| 02AI01-0006 | 25/15/50 |

Comment: What is the logic being applied here?  What have you tried so far?  What issues are you facing?

Comment: An explanation would be nice, and your existing attempt too.

Comment: I have tried to build the query with the help of Row_Number and XML Path i got the result        02AI01-0006 15/ 25/50 but what i need is it should not sort the result 02AI01-0006 25/15/50

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your attempt

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it:

```
select distinct col1
 ,  ( select distinct cast(col2 as varchar(100)) +'/'
      from data d2
      where d2.col1 = d1.col1
      for xml path('')
     )
from data d1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=784588cf6ac458ffb284708d543e5542)*

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. but the result set is in sorted order format, i need data combined based on RowID, as like below
02AD04-0037 20 
02AI01-0001 50/15 
02AI01-0002 50/15 
02AI01-0006 25/15/50